# What technique was used to transform Captain America from thinner and smaller into stronger and longer?

Tags: shooting, visual-effects

I would like to know what technique they used to show Chris Evans smaller and  thinner in Captain America The First Avenger.

What is the name of this video editing trick?

How Chris Evans Captain America body transformation happened?

[image: captain america transformation]

Comment: There is no trick, it's simply hard work and well planned shots. Have a look into: http://www.fxguide.com/featured/case-study-how-to-make-a-captain-america-wimp/

Comment: Honestly @poor, you should rephrase that as an answer, because, well, it is.